# Update one2many field with Onchange . Odoo 14

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, orm, odoo

I tried to update  One2many field with the following function called in pos.order.line model because of problem of not saving the field  'tax_ids_after_fiscal_position'
Here is my code :

```
class PosOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = "pos.order.line" 

    @api.onchange('product_id')
    def _onchange_product_id(self):
        self.tax_ids_after_fiscal_position = self.product_id.taxes_id
        self.write({'tax_ids_after_fiscal_position': [(4, self.product_id.taxes_id)]})
```

I got the following  error :

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
AttributeError: 'account.tax' object has no attribute 'ref'
```

What's wrong please?
Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't use Odoo. If you'd really like to do something that doesn't involve much coding, use Bubble. I used to work with this stuff professionally. It's garbage.

Comment: Can you post the file? It doesn't seem like that is where the error originates.

Comment: @Juliana Hill , which file?

Comment: It looks like it might have to do with: `self.write({'tax_ids_after_fiscal_position': [(4, self.product_id.taxes_id)]})` I'm not quite sure I fully remember this, but I think the number value for the tuple is wrong.

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.write

Comment: I think the issue is this: `(6, 0, ids)`

Comment: @Juliana Hill , I got this error in onchange : The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'account.tax'

Comment: when printing field in onchange function, I got : tax_ids_after_fiscal_position:account.tax(<NewId origin=3>, <NewId origin=7>, <NewId origin=8>) , @CZoellner

Comment: Interesting but not what i was asking for. I just want to know, how the field itself is defined in Odoo.

Comment: tax_ids_after_fiscal_position = fields.Many2many('account.tax', compute='_get_tax_ids_after_fiscal_position', string='Taxes to Apply') ,standard Odoo ,@CZoellner

Comment: @K.ju sorry, I took a break for a bit and did not get to respond. I hope you guys have figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use write inside onchange.

```
@api.onchange('product_id')
def _onchange_product_id(self):
    self.tax_ids_after_fiscal_position =  [(6, 0,self.product_id.taxes_id.ids)]
```

Comment: @K.ju did you try that?

Comment: I tried this solution , always problem when saving , I also try to add store = True , but this not solve the issue. ; The field tax_ids_after_fiscal_position is a compute field , I don't know if this cause a problem when storing field in database.... @Juliana Hill

Comment: @K.ju That's why! you cannot save on top of a computed field with Odoo. You have to redefine the field within the database

Comment: I used to have code that experimented with these concepts, but I'm not quite sure where those repos are...probably on an old expired account for Odoo lol

Comment: The only way to do what you are asking is to recalculate the computed field by overwriting the corresponding function while inheriting the model

Comment: That's part of the reason I think it's garbage...because, it claims to make coding easier when it's actually pretty difficult still...which is why Bubble is not a bad alternative

Comment: You mean that I have to add this in the inherit model?  @Juliana Hill tax_ids_after_fiscal_position = fields.Many2many('account.tax', compute='_get_tax_ids_after_fiscal_position', string='Taxes to Apply')
    
    @api.depends('order_id', 'order_id.fiscal_position_id')
    def _get_tax_ids_after_fiscal_position(self):
        for line in self:
            line.tax_ids_after_fiscal_position = line.order_id.fiscal_position_id.map_tax(line.tax_ids, line.product_id,
                                                                                          line.order_id.partner_id)

Comment: Essentially, yes. It's hard for me to read it though! But, that's the general idea :) good job!